# Configure MQTT mosquitto server for username + client certificate

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I want to configure mosquitto MQTT broker in way that a client connecting to it must provide username + client certificate. Here username provided must be matching to CN of the passed client certificate.

This is the same thing what [Azure event grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/mqtt-client-authentication#self-signed-client-certificate---thumbprint) is doing. So I wanted to simulate the same thing with mosquitto for testing purpose.

I have tried to set `require_certificate` and `use_identity_as_username` to true, but with this configuration, broker is allowing any user name while connecting to broker. I want broker should verify if the user name provided in connect packet is matching with CN in client certificate. Any plugin would help?

Comment: Please include your moquitto.conf in the question

Comment: You may need to write an authentication plugin to enforce this requirement, I don't think mosquitto on it's own will do it for you. The `use_identity_as_username` will replace any username passed in.

Comment: @hardillb any guide (forum/howto) on how can I write and build authentication plugin?

Comment: The best example is the go-auth-plugin https://github.com/iegomez/mosquitto-go-auth